# Can I do two factor repeated measures ANOVA with differing numbers of measures per group?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, missing-data

I want to compare reaction time in four groups but I have three measures (pretest,post test and delayed post test) only in one of the groups. it was impossible to give post test and delayed post test in the other two groups and in the last group just possible to give pretest and post test, and only the first group received treatment. Now I want to see whether reaction times has decrees during time? Now since in three of the groups measurement has been down incompletely and no treatment has been given, can I use the previous measures for the lacking measures and use repeated measure ANOVA?

Comment: The method you have suggested is called [last observation carried forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_observation_carried_forward#Last_observation_carried_forward). It is generally not recommended.

Comment: I agree with Gung. But if you tell us more about what these groups are, what you are trying to find out, and so on, we might be able to suggest a better analysis.